# Setup Kmail with Gmail

Tags: gmail, imap, kmail

I want to use IMAP to connect Kmail to Gmail. After setting up the account via wizard in kmail, I get this error (I replaced my email address with abc) :

```
The server for account "Google Mail (abc)" refused the supplied username and password. Do you want to go to the settings, have another attempt at logging in, or do nothing?

Login failed, server replied: A000002 NO Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/78754 ( Failure ) [ ALERT  ]
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS with KDE

I followed steps written [here](https://userbase.kde.org/Working_with_GMail/pt-br).

Answer (score 3):

Google marks Email clients as less secure way of accessing Gmail. The most secure way would be using latest browser.

All you have to do first login in Google and visit [Less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)  and select **Turn ON**
After this try to setup Gmail account in Kmail again

Comment: I dont want to use less secure apps so I should try another email client. but which one?

Comment: @Woeistg it is safe btw, yes you can try other email clients too. search for 'email clients for linux'. which one is allowed by google, you have find it by trying

Comment: @Woeistg this answer is the solution for you question, you might wanna try this one out

Answer (score 0):

The error is fairly explanatory.  You have a login failure, and your so your provided credentials were refused, meaning they may not be accurate.

As well, [read up on this help page from Google](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257?rd=1), which that error message gives you, to see what other troubleshooting options exist.

Comment: My username and pass are correct. I also dont use 2-Step Verification.

Comment: Then verify all connection settings - because something's wrong, and it's not working as it should.

Comment: You mean in gmail setting or Kmail?

Comment: Is there any where in internet steps to setup gmail account in Kmail?

Comment: @Woeistg Have you check out Gmail setting? Maybe you turn off (disable) IMAP or POP3 remote protocol?

Comment: Imap is enabled. I tried with both POP3 on and off without any success